# JS mouseover,hover

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to use js and create "description box" with some "info text"

HTML

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="onmo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> <a onmouseover="info()"  href="http://www.google.com"> google </a> </div> 
</body>
```

JS

```
function info() {}
```

i don't know which code creates so called "description box" with some text.
any help?
without css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jquery-ui tooltip` for this purpose.

Here is link with the documentation with great examples: [Link](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Example from `jqueryui` site:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<p><a href="#" title="That&apos;s what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover
the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
<a href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes."></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show  you some text when hovering the link:

```html
 <a href="http://www.google.com" title="This is Google"> google </a>
```

Comment: Yeah,i know about that one,but i specifically need JS

Comment: @joki00 describe what it should look like

Comment: simple one,with 1 sentence of "info" like with HTML title option

Comment: so it should look exactly the same. But why do you want to use JS then?

Comment: Specifically asks for it...i know its a bother but.. that's the way it is

Comment: well the simplest way might be using that jQuery solution from the other answer